# how to request and post an object to a foreignkey field

Tags: python, django

When I do this exactly as provided below, a shipping address object is created without the customer assigned in the shipping address foreignkey field, I can add it from the admin panel manually but I'm not able to make it work through code, idk what I'm doing wrong, please help!

```
**models.py**

class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150)

class ShippingAddress(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    address_one = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address_two = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...

**views.py**
    
def checkout(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
    else:
        items = []
        order = {'get_cart_total': 0, 'get_cart_items': 0}


    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ShippingForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            #how do I get the customer to get added in the foreignkey field for the shipping address model

            form.save()
            return redirect('store:checkout_shipping')
        else:
            form = ShippingForm()

    else:
        form = ShippingForm()

    context = {"items": items, "order": order, "form": form}
    return render(request, 'store/checkout.html', context)
```

Comment: Can you add your ShippingForm code there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to your comment `#how do I get the customer to get added...` etc, in the case that your `ShippingForm()` points to your `ShippingAddress` model, or at least something with a `customer` foreign key field, you may need to do something like this:

```
def checkout(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
    else:
        items = []
        order = {'get_cart_total': 0, 'get_cart_items': 0}


    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ShippingForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            new_shipment = form.save(commit=False)
            new_shipment.customer = customer
            new_shipment.save()
            return redirect('store:checkout_shipping')
        else:
            form = ShippingForm()

    else:
        form = ShippingForm()

    context = {"items": items, "order": order, "form": form}
    return render(request, 'store/checkout.html', context)
```

Using `commit=False` on the form.save() will allow you to subsequently modify other fields, in this case, by adding the customer relation, then saving it.  [More information here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) in the Django documentation.  Salient quote:

> This save() method accepts an optional commit keyword argument, which
> accepts either True or False. If you call save() with commit=False,
> then it will return an object that hasn’t yet been saved to the
> database. In this case, it’s up to you to call save() on the resulting
> model instance. This is useful if you want to do custom processing on
> the object before saving it, or if you want to use one of the
> specialized model saving options. commit is True by default.

"Custom processing" in this case is the creation of the foreign key relationship to the model instance (customer).

Comment: I get an indentation error at 'POST:' do u know what's going wrong?

Comment: Double check your indentation.  The error might be telling you exactly what the problem is.  Also some code editors will mix spaces and tabs if you haven't set tabs to be made up of spaces.  That can frustrating thing to debug.

Comment: Indentation is alright, but still getting that error

Comment: If you're getting that error, indentation is almost certainly not alright, OR, something above or below your code where the error happens is not alright, like a function that isn't closed, missing colon, or something.  Are you using VSCode?  Some editors will show you dots or spaces for invisible indents if you highlight a selection of code.  You might have to tinker.

Comment: you're right, it was the editor cache, cleared it and restarted the system it works thx man

Comment: That pesky editor cache! Glad it's working :) You're most welcome.